# Regular expression not matching particular non standard characters by Hex or decimal code

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var regex = /^.*[\xC0\xC1\xC2\xC3\xC4\xC7\xC8\xC9\xCA\xCB\xCC\xCD\xCE\xCF\xD1\xA5\xD2\xD3\xD4\xD5\xD6\x8A\xD9\xDA\xDB\xDC\xDD\xDE\x9E\x8E].*/;
//check if text contains any of ÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖŠÚÛÜÙÝŸŽ
if (text.match(regex)) {
    console.log(text);
}
```

Does anyone know why above doesn't match ŠŸŽ? Those are `\x8A`, `\x9E` and `\x9F`. It works for all apart of these three. I also tried `\u0138`, `\u0159` and `\u0158`.

Is there any other way to match them?

Comment: How did you get those character values? I'm seeing `\u0160`, `\u0178`, and `\u017d` for `Š`, `Ÿ`, and `Ž`. I got those values from `"Ž".charCodeAt(0).toString(16)` (with each character), and they work when I include them.

Comment: http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: everything came from here http://www.ascii-code.com/ I confirmed on other sites and everywhere values are the same. why is it different in JavaScript and why only for these 3? Anyway thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table where you found those character values says:

> The table below is according to ISO 8859-1, also called ISO Latin-1.

(Note that this table is actually not even ISO 8859-1, but rather a superset of it called [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).)

Section 2 of the ECMAScript 5 specification says

> A conforming implementation of this Standard shall interpret characters in conformance with the Unicode Standard... with either UCS-2 or UTF-16 as the adopted encoding form, implementation level 3.

JavaScript characters are always treated as UTF-16 or UCS-2 characters.

In Windows-1252, the character value `8A` corresponds to the character called `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CARON`. In UTF-16, the code point `008A` is the non-printable character named `LINE TABULATION SET` (See the [PDF of the `008x` range from unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf).)

In UTF-16, the captial-S-with-caron character is at code point `0160`.

If you want to know the Unicode code point of a character, you find it easily by running the code `"X".charCodeAt(0).toString(16)` (where `X` is the character you want to inspect).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're trying to match the hex or decimal instead of the literal character, the following regex works for me:

```
var subject = "ÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖŠÚÛÜÙÝŸŽ";
if (/[ÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖŠÚÛÜÙÝŸŽ]/i.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Regex Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/fR6uT6/1